# Chart.js + Wordpress cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, undefined, chart.js

I'm trying to get chart.js to work on my wordpress through the CDN. I am simply trying to implement the first example on the chart.js docs page under "Creating a Chart" (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

I have the code in a jQuery document ready function, and I have made sure that I can access the DOM and the canvas element with a console log.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
console.log(ctx);
```

which returns the canvas element to the console. The rest of the code follows the example in the chart.js docs EXACTLY.

I am getting an error in the console as stated in the title, which is:

> Chart.min.js?ver=4.5.3:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined(…)

Looking at the error in the chart.js file in the chrome inspector it looks like the canvas element isn't being passed into the Chart function:

```
var Chart = function(s) { ... };
```

I see "s" as undefined.

Thoughts? I feel lost.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Does the error happen before your `$(window).on("load", ...` function starts?  You could put a `console.log()` at the start of the function to check.   If you are sure the canvas element is ready when the script is run, maybe add more details/code the the question.

Comment: I tried using a $(window).on("load", ... as well to no avail. I even tried a setTimeout with 10 seconds wait time and did the console log in there before the Chart script ran. The canvas element logged properly but I got the same error (cannot read property 'width' of undefined). The only code I'm using is in the link to the docs page on chart.js. I know the script is loaded as I can see it in the console window.

Comment: Basically I am just suggesting my standard debugging ideas.  It looks like a trace in the console message `(…)` that you can click on and see.  I realize that you probably know where the call is coming from, but maybe you can insert breakpoints in the script and see if anything else is odd.  Also, it may help you and answerers if you created a [mcve].